# Negative index of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

**Definition.** $\big($Definition $5.2.9$ of [$1$]$\big)$. Let a self-adjoint operator $L: D(L) \subset X \longrightarrow X$, with  $X$ a Hilbert space. Suppose that $L$ generates a continuous bilinear form on $Y \subset X$ in the $X$ inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$. The negative index $n_Y(L)$ that denotes the dimension of the largest subspace $K \subset Y$ over which the bilinear form $b$ associated with $L$ is negative,
$$b(v,v):= (L(v),v)<0, \; \forall \; v \in K\setminus\{0\}.$$

**Question.** In view of this definition, what is a **negative index** of a matrix $A$, with entries in $\mathbb{R}$?

In this case, is the same of the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$?

[[$1$]](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-6995-7) Kapitula T, Promislow K. *Spectral and Dynamical Stability of Nonlinear Waves*. New York, US: Springer-Verlag. $2013$.

Comment: The $A$ you selected is not self adjoint.

Comment: I removed such matrix. But my question still remains, more generally.

Comment: Yes, this would be the number of negative eigenvalues.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Could you please put that as an answer?